# How to add custom styling to Forms created with Django CreateView

Tags: django

I am very new to Django. Following some tutorials I have managed to create a form using the Python Generic Views (**CreateView**)

I have a 'Question' Model

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    asked_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

and using this model I have created a View Class

```
class QuestionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'category']
```

This does generate a nice HTML form. But how do I pass CSS attributes to each field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write a model form for Question and pass it to the create view,

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('myfield1', 'myfield2) 
        widgets = {
        'myfield1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        }
```

or you could override init method for specifying a certain class for every field,

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['myfield1'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'myfieldclass'})
```

Then, pass it to the attribute `form_class` of `CreateView`,

```
class QuestionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem in my Django application based on the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) framework. My first attempt:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from . import models

class ModuleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Module
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'status']
```

looked as follow:

[image: First attempt]

Not very nice indeed! The second attempt implied defining a custom *ModelForm* for my view and applying all the customisations therein:

```
# forms.py
from .models import Module

class ModuleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModuleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'status']
```

Please note the *for* cycle in `__init__`, which adds the *form-control* CSS class to all visible form fields. The CSS styling for *form-control* is provided by Bootstrap so I didn't even have to modify my stylesheets.

Once I have my custom *ModelForm* I can rewrite my View class as follows:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from . import forms, models

class ModuleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Module
    form_class = forms.ModuleForm
```

and you can see the results below.

[image: Second attempt]

**Far better!**

Hope that helps, feel free to comment in case of questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field1'].widget.attrs = { 'class': 'fooclass' }

    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

you cannot directly add `css` to the `CreateView` for that you need to create a `ModelForm` and use the `form_class = FooForm` in your create view, and in this `ModelForm` you can use specific class for the fields and use css to style them as needed

Comment: quite the inconvenience right.. one would think there will be simple way to style in the html form accompanying the createview, debugging the form object there is media field containing css and js lists which are empty though, maybe there is a way to add some styles

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to override the `get_form` function.

```
class QuestionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'category', 'MyField']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(QuestionCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form['MyField'].field.widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'MyClass'})
        return form
```

Or if you want to add the attribute to all fields you can use a for-loop as follows:

```
class QuestionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'category', 'MyField']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(OPCCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        for visible in form.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'MyClass'})
        return form
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use django-crispy-forms if we want some bootstrap styling to the rendered form:

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

Then add 'crispy-forms' to the installed apps.
Load the crispy_form_tags in the form template page and instead of {{form}} use {{form|crispy}}.

Documentation of [Crispy](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html).