# Change class for CreateView Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have CreateView and I want add class for fields
views.py:

```py
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model = apps.blog.models.Post
    fields = ['name', 'content', 'photo']
    template_name = 'cabinet/post/create.html'
```

and in template:

```html
{% extends 'cabinet/includes/main.html' %}
{% block title %}Створити новину{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="." method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.media }}
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And in output I have

```html
<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="250" required="" id="id_name"></p>
```

but I want have `<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="250" required="" class="form-control" id="id_name">`

Comment: did you tried to write custom form class? you can specify the html attributes with it.
this could help your need
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492495/12306993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `ModelForm` where you specify the `class="…"` for (certain) widgets:

```
# app_name/forms.py

from apps.blog.models import Post
from django import forms

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['name', 'content', 'photo']
```

Then we can use that form in our `CreatePostView`:

```
class CreatePostView(CreateView):
    model = apps.blog.models.Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'cabinet/post/create.html'
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `CreatePostView`, instead of <s>`CreatePost`</s>.