# Django AssertionError when testing Create View

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-testing

I'm running some tests for my app 'ads', but when I try to test the CreateView it fails with the following message:

> AssertionError: 'just a test' != 'New title'

Here's the test:

```
class AdTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='test_user',
            email='test@email.com',
            password='secret'
        )
        self.ad = Ad.objects.create(
            title='just a test',
            text='Ehy',
            owner=self.user
        )

    def test_ad_create_view(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('ads:ad_create'), {
            'title': 'New title',
            'text': 'New text',
            'owner': self.user.id,
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(Ad.objects.last().title, 'New title')
        self.assertEqual(Ad.objects.last().text, 'New text')
```

So it could be that the test fails in creating a new ad, and then it compares the fields with the first ad in the setUp method.
I upload the rest of the code if it can help:

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from . import views


app_name='ads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AdListView.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('ad/<int:pk>', views.AdDetailView.as_view(), name='ad_detail'),
    path('ad/create',
        views.AdCreateView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('ads:all')), name='ad_create'),
    ...
]
```

> models.py

```
class Ad(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(
            max_length=200,
            validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Title must be greater than 2 characters")]
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    """We use AUTH_USER_MODEL (which has a default value if it is not specified in settings.py) to create a Foreign Key relationship between the Ad model 
    and a django built-in User model"""
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Comment', related_name='comments_owned')
    picture = models.BinaryField(null=True, editable=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, help_text='The MIMEType of the file')
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Fav', related_name='favorite_ads')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

> views.py

```
class AdCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'ads/ad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ads:all')

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        form = CreateForm()
        ctx = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    # Pull data
    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        form = CreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if not form.is_valid():
            ctx = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

        pic = form.save(commit=False)
        pic.owner = self.request.user
        pic.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

> forms.py (the view uses it especially to check and save the image)

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    max_upload_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
    max_upload_limit_text = naturalsize(max_upload_limit)

    # Call this 'picture' so it gets copied from the form to the in-memory model
    # It will not be the "bytes", it will be the "InMemoryUploadedFile"
    # because we need to pull out things like content_type
    picture = forms.FileField(required=False, label='File to Upload <= ' + max_upload_limit_text)
    upload_field_name = 'picture'

    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'price', 'picture', 'tags']

    # Check if the size of the picture is less than the one specified (see above).
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pic = cleaned_data.get('picture')
        if pic is None:
            return
        if len(pic) > self.max_upload_limit:
            self.add_error('picture', "File must be < " + self.max_upload_limit_text + " bytes")

    # Convert uploaded File object to a picture
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(CreateForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # We only need to adjust picture if it is a freshly uploaded file
        f = instance.picture  # Make a copy
        if isinstance(f, InMemoryUploadedFile):  # Extract data from the form to the model
            bytearr = f.read()
            instance.content_type = f.content_type
            instance.picture = bytearr  # Overwrite with the actual image data

        if commit:
            instance.save()
            self.save_m2m()

        return instance
```

I hope it is useful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[According to Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView)

Create View:

A view that displays a form for creating an object, redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving the object.

This is not a Valid way to do create View based on my experience. Check the doc [Doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView).

if i understand what you are talking about You want to submit Ad Model using Create View, if you want to submit it in form You can something like this:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy,

class PostCreativeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = #Your Model
    fields = [#Fields of the model You want to submit]
    template_name = #html template you want to submit the form
    success_url = reverse_lazy(#url for redirected user when the form is submitted)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (PostCreativeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

in the form template you can add:

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

for styling you can follow this: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64317285/19255291)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with the view? I didn't really understand

Comment: @materialAres You can try what i have edited now

Comment: @Berita I tried, but it gave me the same result. Plus, I had to add some code to your view, otherwise the picture cannot be loaded anymore, so basically I merged methods from the original view to yours. I think that the original view depends on the CreateForm to work correctly

Comment: @materialAres Does that works for you or not ? Please specify

Comment: @Berita no, it doesn't work. Specifically, the view works, but the test fails with the same AssertionError message